# SQL pivot result simplification

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a exchange rate table in my ms-sql database, and when I query last date rates:

```
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM tblKur ORDER BY tarih DESC
```

[image: result of query]

I wrote a pivot query but it gives me nulls,

```
SELECT top 4 piv.* FROM tblKur
PIVOT(
       MAX(satis)
       FOR dovizId IN([1],[2],[3],[4])
)AS Piv
ORDER BY  tarih DESC
```

[image: pivot result]

I need simplify my pivot result such form:

[image]

How can I do this process?

Comment: try with `cte, ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  [1] as 1,[2] as 2,[3] as 3,[4]  as 4     
        FROM        
        (
            SELECT top 4 dovizId ,satis FROM tblKur  ORDER BY tarih DESC
        )PivoitData

        PIVOT
        (
        SUM(satis) for dovizId  in ([1],[2],[3],[4])        
        ) AS Pivoting
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   SELECT  [1] as 1,[2] as 2,[3] as 3,[4]  as 4     
        FROM        
        (
            SELECT dovizId ,satis FROM tblKur
        )PivoitData

        PIVOT
        (
        SUM(satis) for dovizId  in ([1],[2],[3],[4])        
        ) AS Pivoting
```